# How to override request limit for AWS RDS Wait command?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a DB Cluster from snapshot and did wait command and got exceeded attempts

so I"m trying to create a script

```
DB_CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER=${1}
DB_CLUSTER_STATUS=$(aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier "$DB_CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER" --query 'DBClusters[*].Status' --output text)

while [ "$DB_CLUSTER_STATUS" != "available" ]; do
  echo "DB cluster is not available"
  sleep 5
  DB_CLUSTER_STATUS=$(aws rds describe-db-clusters --db-cluster-identifier "$DB_CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER" --query 'DBClusters[*].Status' --output text)
done

aws rds wait db-cluster-available --db-cluster-identifier "$DB_CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER"
```

i'm scared DB_CLUSTER_STATUS != "available" is invalid

How does one override the request limit?

Comment: You can't. The values are hardcoded.

Comment: SDKs like boto3 implement a backoff retry to account for the API rate limiting